# JAXB XmlElementRef lookup into entire classpath

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, jaxb, jaxb2

Hi can someone please explain how to solve following problem.
i have class structure like this..

```
 public class RequestWrapper implements Seriallizable
 {
    private List<Request> requests = null;
    @XmlElementRefs( { @XmlElementRef(type = Class1.class), @XmlElementRef(type = Class2.class), .. And so on } )
    public List<Request> getRequests()
    {
        return requests;
    }
 }
```

This Request class is an Abstract class. Many Classes in the project extending this Request class. For this reason i can't add code by declaring many @XmlElementRef annotations.

Is there any way this @XmlElementRefs tag can lookup entire class path instead of looking only declared @XmlElementRef.

Kindly reply to this post quickly...

Answer (score 2):

**Making the `JAXBContext` Aware of the Subclasses**

A [**JAXB (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) implementation cannot determine subclasses of a mapped type by reflection or scanning the classpath.  You will need to explicitly tell JAXB to include them.  This can be done in one of the following ways.

***Option #1 - `@XmlSeeAlso` Annotation***

The `@XmlSeeAlso` annotation is a mechanism you can leverage in a mapped class to have other classes included.  This is typically leveraged to pull in any subclasses that JAXB should treat as mapped classes.

```
@XmlSeeAlso({Class1.class, Class2.class})
public class Request {
}
```

***Option #2 - Include them When Creating `JAXBContext`***

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Class1.class, Class2.class);
```

---

**Applying `@XmlElementRef`**

As long as your `JAXBContext` is aware of all the subclases of `Request` then you can simplify your mapping down to the following:

```
@XmlElementRef
public List<Request> getRequests()
{
    return requests;
}
```

---

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html

Comment: Thanks a lot Blaise for your quick response.

Comment: @KiranT - There is no versions of JAXB (JSR-222) that will auto detect subclasses of a mapped class.   You could potentially implement some code that takes the classes you wish to bootstrap the `JAXBContext` on and then expand it to include all subclasses using some mechanism and then use the expanded array of classes to build the `JAXBContext`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Blaise.. Useful information. Actually i too thinking to pass custom class loader to JAXBContect..